# Ошибка при построении классов методология БЭМ

Tags: html, бэм

Есть код:

```html
<section class="head-slider">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="head-slider__slider">
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <div class="slide__slide-header">
          <h2>Expire</h2>
          <svg class='underline'>
            <use xlink:href='img/sprite.svg#mobile'/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide-description">
          <p>Professionaly designed, carefully made for your enjoyement</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide-buttons">
          <a href="#">Explore</a>
          <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--slide-end-->
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <div class="slide__slide-header">
          <h2>Expire</h2>
          <object data="" type=""></object>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide-description">
          <p>Professionaly designed, carefully made for your enjoyement</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide-buttons">
          <a href="#">Explore</a>
          <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--slide-end-->
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <div class="slide__slide-header">
          <h2>Expire</h2>
          <object data="" type=""></object>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide-description">
          <p>Professionaly designed, carefully made for your enjoyement</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide-buttons">
          <a href="#">Explore</a>
          <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--slide-end-->
      <div class="slider__slide">
        <div class="slide__slide-header">
          <h2>Expire</h2>
          <object data="" type=""></object>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide-description">
          <p>Professionaly designed, carefully made for your enjoyement</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slide__slide-buttons">
          <a href="#">Explore</a>
          <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--slide-end-->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Присутствует такой класс `.slider__slide`, но в дальнейшей верстке на такой класс можно выйти еще несколько раз, когда добавляешь еще слайдеры. Где я допускаю ошибку в именовании классов?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы знаете, что блок или предполагаемый элемент будет использоваться в других местах и в другом окружении, то необходимо делать этот блок отдельно и именовать независимо от окружения. То есть ваш **.slider__slide** может называться например **slide-container**, а сам **slider__slide** может быть миксом в данном окружении вместо модификатора и называться **slider__slide-container** в блоке slider, но у вас его нет...

В целом по вашей разметки понятно, что вы не поняли методологию БЭМ. Ваш элемент **slider__slide** является элементом какого блока по вашей версии? По методологии он должен являться элементом блока **slider**, которого у вас нет.
**slide__slide-header** должен быть элементом блока **slide**, которого у вас тоже нет.

В общих чертах ваши классы должны именоваться примерно так:

```
slider
slider__container
slider__slide
slider__item
slider__head
slider__header
slider__title
slider__description
slider__buttons
```

И неважно насколько глубоко вложены ваши блоки друг в друга. 
Сейчас у вас допустим в элементе **slider__container** находятся:

```
slider__title
slider__description
slider__buttons
```

И методология БЭМ подразумевает, что вы можете достать из этого элемента другой элемент, например **slider__title** и поставить его рядом на одном уровне. При этом вы не потеряете связи. 
Сейчас у вас в разметке какая-то тавтология и похоже, что вы пытаетесь для каждого элемента определить родителя и завязываетесь на иерархию, на каскад именнований от которого, как раз и необходимо избавляться.

Дефис в классическом БЭМ не разделяет элементы и блоки, это просто имя из двух и более слов, Например: *Мой-**Б**лок__мой-**Э**лемент_мой-**М**одификатор*

Answer (score -1):

Добавь элементу `.head-slider__slider` класс `.slider` и получишь правильный БЭМ. Теперь через класс `.head-slider__slider`сможешь задавать внешнюю геометрию в блоке `.head-slider`, а блок `.slide` использовать в любом месте верстки.